# ListItem avatar not displaying while rendering in EXPO

Tags: react-native, expo, listitem, avatar, react-native-elements

```
  <ListItem key={index}>
         <Avatar rounded source={require('./images/alberto.png')} />
         <ListItem.Content>
               <ListItem.Title>{item.name}</ListItem.Title>
                <ListItem.Subtitle>{item.description}</ListItem.Subtitle>
         </ListItem.Content>
    </ListItem>
```

This is my code and the image is not rendering although the source is correct, need some help.
Thanks in advance